# how to pass value inside a class variable

Tags: php, api

I am working on a payment gateway payfort, here I want to pass my dynamic price **public $amount = 7150.00;** by Url request, but it's not working.
I am new on OOPS so please any one help me.

Static value are working fine.

**confirm-order.php**

```
<?php include('header.php') ?>
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST;
$itemname = $data['startfrom'].' - '. $data['stopto'].', Distance : '. $data['distance'].' Km , Duration : '.$data['duration'].' Minutes';
require_once 'PayfortIntegration.php';
$objFort = new PayfortIntegration();
$amount =  $objFort->amount;
$currency = $objFort->currency;
$totalAmount = $data['amount'];
$paymentMethod = $_REQUEST['payment_method'];
$objFort->itemName = $itemname;
$objFort->customerEmail = 'abc@gmail.com';
?>

    <section class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="lead" >Payment Method</li>
            <li class="lead active" > Pay</li>
            <li class="lead" > Done</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="confirmation">
        <label>Confirm Your Order</label>
    </section>
    <section class="order-info">
        <ul class="items">
            <span>
                <i class="icon icon-bag"></i>
                <label class="lead" for="">Your Booking</label>
            </span>
            <li><?php echo $objFort->itemName ?></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="v-seperator"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="price">
            <span>
                <i class="icon icon-tag"></i>
                <label class="lead" for="">price</label>
            </span>
            <li><span class="curreny">AED</span> <?php echo sprintf("%.2f",$totalAmount);?> </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="items">
            <span>
                <i class="icon icon-bag"></i>
                <label class="lead" for="">Payment Method</label>
            </span>
            <li><?php echo $objFort->getPaymentOptionName($paymentMethod) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <?php if($paymentMethod == 'cc_merchantpage') ://merchant page iframe method ?>
        <section class="merchant-page-iframe">
            <?php
                $merchantPageData = $objFort->getMerchantPageData();
                $postData = $merchantPageData['params'];
                $gatewayUrl = $merchantPageData['url'];
            ?>
                        <p>Test card: 4005550000000001<br/>05/17<br/>123</p>
            <div class="cc-iframe-display">
                <div id="div-pf-iframe" style="display:none">
                    <div class="pf-iframe-container">
                        <div class="pf-iframe" id="pf_iframe_content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="h-seperator"></div>
    <section class="actions">
        <a class="back" id="btn_back" href="index.php">Back</a>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/checkout.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var paymentMethod = '<?php echo $paymentMethod?>';
            //load merchant page iframe
            if(paymentMethod == 'cc_merchantpage') {
                getPaymentPage(paymentMethod);
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php include('footer.php') ?>
```

and configuration file is:

**PayfortIntegration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright Copyright PayFort 2012-2016 
 * 
 */
class PayfortIntegration
{

    public $gatewayHost        = 'https://checkout.payfort.com/';
    public $gatewaySandboxHost = 'https://sbcheckout.payfort.com/';
    public $language           = 'en';
    /**
     * @var string your Merchant Identifier account (mid)
     */
    public $merchantIdentifier = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    /**
     * @var string your access code
     */
    public $accessCode         = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';

    /**
     * @var string SHA Request passphrase
     */
    public $SHARequestPhrase   = 'XXXXXXXXX';

    /**
     * @var string SHA Response passphrase
     */
    public $SHAResponsePhrase = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

    /**
     * @var string SHA Type (Hash Algorith)
     * expected Values ("sha1", "sha256", "sha512")
     */
    public $SHAType       = 'sha256';

    /**
     * @var string  command
     * expected Values ("AUTHORIZATION", "PURCHASE")
     */
    public $command       = 'AUTHORIZATION';

    /**
     * @var decimal order amount
     */
    public $amount             = 7150.00;

    /**
     * @var string order currency
     */
    public $currency           = 'AED';

    /**
     * @var string item name
     */
    public $itemName           = 'Apple iPhone 6s Plus';

    /**
     * @var string you can change it to your email
     */
    public $customerEmail      = 'shiv@srapsware.com';

    /**
     * @var boolean for live account change it to false
     */
    public $sandboxMode        = true;
    /**
     * @var string  project root folder
     * change it if the project is not on root folder.
     */
    public $projectUrlPath     = '/pay'; 

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function processRequest($paymentMethod)
    {
        if ($paymentMethod == 'cc_merchantpage' || $paymentMethod == 'cc_merchantpage2') {
            $merchantPageData = $this->getMerchantPageData();
            $postData = $merchantPageData['params'];
            $gatewayUrl = $merchantPageData['url'];
        }
        else{
            $data = $this->getRedirectionData($paymentMethod);
            $postData = $data['params'];
            $gatewayUrl = $data['url'];
        }
        $form = $this->getPaymentForm($gatewayUrl, $postData);
        echo json_encode(array('form' => $form, 'url' => $gatewayUrl, 'params' => $postData, 'paymentMethod' => $paymentMethod));
        exit;
    }

    public function getRedirectionData($paymentMethod) {
        $merchantReference = $this->generateMerchantReference();
        if ($this->sandboxMode) {
            $gatewayUrl = $this->gatewaySandboxHost . 'FortAPI/paymentPage';
        }
        else {
            $gatewayUrl = $this->gatewayHost . 'FortAPI/paymentPage';
        }

        if ($paymentMethod == 'sadad') {
            $this->currency = 'SAR';
        }
        $postData = array(
            'amount'              => $this->convertFortAmount($this->amount, $this->currency),
            'currency'            => strtoupper($this->currency),
            'merchant_identifier' => $this->merchantIdentifier,
            'access_code'         => $this->accessCode,
            'merchant_reference'  => $merchantReference,
            'customer_email'      => 'test@payfort.com',
            //'customer_name'         => trim($order_info['b_firstname'].' '.$order_info['b_lastname']),
            'command'             => $this->command,
            'language'            => $this->language,
            'return_url'          => $this->getUrl('route.php?r=processResponse'),
        );

        if ($paymentMethod == 'sadad') {
            $postData['payment_option'] = 'SADAD';
        }
        elseif ($paymentMethod == 'naps') {
            $postData['payment_option']    = 'NAPS';
            $postData['order_description'] = $this->itemName;
        }
        elseif ($paymentMethod == 'installments') {
            $postData['installments']    = 'STANDALONE';
            $postData['command']         = 'PURCHASE';
        }
        $postData['signature'] = $this->calculateSignature($postData, 'request');
        $debugMsg = "Fort Redirect Request Parameters \n".print_r($postData, 1);
        $this->log($debugMsg);
        return array('url' => $gatewayUrl, 'params' => $postData);
    }

    public function getMerchantPageData()
    {
        $merchantReference = $this->generateMerchantReference();
        $returnUrl = $this->getUrl('route.php?r=merchantPageReturn');
        if(isset($_GET['3ds']) && $_GET['3ds'] == 'no') {
            $returnUrl = $this->getUrl('route.php?r=merchantPageReturn&3ds=no');
        }
        $iframeParams              = array(
            'merchant_identifier' => $this->merchantIdentifier,
            'access_code'         => $this->accessCode,
            'merchant_reference'  => $merchantReference,
            'service_command'     => 'TOKENIZATION',
            'language'            => $this->language,
            'return_url'          => $returnUrl,
        );
        $iframeParams['signature'] = $this->calculateSignature($iframeParams, 'request');

        if ($this->sandboxMode) {
            $gatewayUrl = $this->gatewaySandboxHost . 'FortAPI/paymentPage';
        }
        else {
            $gatewayUrl = $this->gatewayHost . 'FortAPI/paymentPage';
        }
        $debugMsg = "Fort Merchant Page Request Parameters \n".print_r($iframeParams, 1);
        $this->log($debugMsg);

        return array('url' => $gatewayUrl, 'params' => $iframeParams);
    }

    public function getPaymentForm($gatewayUrl, $postData)
    {
        $form = '<form style="display:none" name="payfort_payment_form" id="payfort_payment_form" method="post" action="' . $gatewayUrl . '">';
        foreach ($postData as $k => $v) {
            $form .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $k . '" value="' . $v . '">';
        }
        $form .= '<input type="submit" id="submit">';
        return $form;
    }

    public function processResponse()
    {
        $fortParams = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

        $debugMsg = "Fort Redirect Response Parameters \n".print_r($fortParams, 1);
        $this->log($debugMsg);

        $reason        = '';
        $response_code = '';
        $success = true;
        if(empty($fortParams)) {
            $success = false;
            $reason = "Invalid Response Parameters";
            $debugMsg = $reason;
            $this->log($debugMsg);
        }
        else{
            //validate payfort response
            $params        = $fortParams;
            $responseSignature     = $fortParams['signature'];
            $merchantReference = $params['merchant_reference'];
            unset($params['r']);
            unset($params['signature']);
            unset($params['integration_type']);
            $calculatedSignature = $this->calculateSignature($params, 'response');
            $success       = true;
            $reason        = '';

            if ($responseSignature != $calculatedSignature) {
                $success = false;
                $reason  = 'Invalid signature.';
                $debugMsg = sprintf('Invalid Signature. Calculated Signature: %1s, Response Signature: %2s', $responseSignature, $calculatedSignature);
                $this->log($debugMsg);
            }
            else {
                $response_code    = $params['response_code'];
                $response_message = $params['response_message'];
                $status           = $params['status'];
                if (substr($response_code, 2) != '000') {
                    $success = false;
                    $reason  = $response_message;
                    $debugMsg = $reason;
                    $this->log($debugMsg);
                }
            }
        }
        if(!$success) {
            $p = $params;
            $p['error_msg'] = $reason;
            $return_url = $this->getUrl('error.php?'.http_build_query($p));
        }
        else{
            $return_url = $this->getUrl('success.php?'.http_build_query($params));
        }
        echo "<html><body onLoad=\"javascript: window.top.location.href='" . $return_url . "'\"></body></html>";
        exit;
    }

    public function processMerchantPageResponse()
    {
        $fortParams = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);

        $debugMsg = "Fort Merchant Page Response Parameters \n".print_r($fortParams, 1);
        $this->log($debugMsg);
        $reason = '';
        $response_code = '';
        $success = true;
        if(empty($fortParams)) {
            $success = false;
            $reason = "Invalid Response Parameters";
            $debugMsg = $reason;
            $this->log($debugMsg);
        }
        else{
            //validate payfort response
            $params        = $fortParams;
            $responseSignature     = $fortParams['signature'];
            unset($params['r']);
            unset($params['signature']);
            unset($params['integration_type']);
            unset($params['3ds']);
            $merchantReference = $params['merchant_reference'];
            $calculatedSignature = $this->calculateSignature($params, 'response');
            $success       = true;
            $reason        = '';

            if ($responseSignature != $calculatedSignature) {
                $success = false;
                $reason  = 'Invalid signature.';
                $debugMsg = sprintf('Invalid Signature. Calculated Signature: %1s, Response Signature: %2s', $responseSignature, $calculatedSignature);
                $this->log($debugMsg);
            }
            else {
                $response_code    = $params['response_code'];
                $response_message = $params['response_message'];
                $status           = $params['status'];
                if (substr($response_code, 2) != '000') {
                    $success = false;
                    $reason  = $response_message;
                    $debugMsg = $reason;
                    $this->log($debugMsg);
                }
                else {
                    $success         = true;
                    $host2HostParams = $this->merchantPageNotifyFort($fortParams);
                    $debugMsg = "Fort Merchant Page Host2Hots Response Parameters \n".print_r($fortParams, 1);
                    $this->log($debugMsg);
                    if (!$host2HostParams) {
                        $success = false;
                        $reason  = 'Invalid response parameters.';
                        $debugMsg = $reason;
                        $this->log($debugMsg);
                    }
                    else {
                        $params    = $host2HostParams;
                        $responseSignature = $host2HostParams['signature'];
                        $merchantReference = $params['merchant_reference'];
                        unset($params['r']);
                        unset($params['signature']);
                        unset($params['integration_type']);
                        $calculatedSignature = $this->calculateSignature($params, 'response');
                        if ($responseSignature != $calculatedSignature) {
                            $success = false;
                            $reason  = 'Invalid signature.';
                            $debugMsg = sprintf('Invalid Signature. Calculated Signature: %1s, Response Signature: %2s', $responseSignature, $calculatedSignature);
                            $this->log($debugMsg);
                        }
                        else {
                            $response_code = $params['response_code'];
                            if ($response_code == '20064' && isset($params['3ds_url'])) {
                                $success = true;
                                $debugMsg = 'Redirect to 3DS URL : '.$params['3ds_url'];
                                $this->log($debugMsg);
                                echo "<html><body onLoad=\"javascript: window.top.location.href='" . $params['3ds_url'] . "'\"></body></html>";
                                exit;
                                //header('location:'.$params['3ds_url']);
                            }
                            else {
                                if (substr($response_code, 2) != '000') {
                                    $success = false;
                                    $reason  = $host2HostParams['response_message'];
                                    $debugMsg = $reason;
                                    $this->log($debugMsg);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!$success) {
                $p = $params;
                $p['error_msg'] = $reason;
                $return_url = $this->getUrl('error.php?'.http_build_query($p));
            }
            else{
                $return_url = $this->getUrl('success.php?'.http_build_query($params));
            }
            echo "<html><body onLoad=\"javascript: window.top.location.href='" . $return_url . "'\"></body></html>";
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function merchantPageNotifyFort($fortParams)
    {
        //send host to host
        if ($this->sandboxMode) {
            $gatewayUrl = $this->gatewaySandboxHost . 'FortAPI/paymentPage';
        }
        else {
            $gatewayUrl = $this->gatewayHost . 'FortAPI/paymentPage';
        }

        $postData      = array(
            'merchant_reference'  => $fortParams['merchant_reference'],
            'access_code'         => $this->accessCode,
            'command'             => $this->command,
            'merchant_identifier' => $this->merchantIdentifier,
            'customer_ip'         => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'amount'              => $this->convertFortAmount($this->amount, $this->currency),
            'currency'            => strtoupper($this->currency),
            'customer_email'      => $this->customerEmail,
            'customer_name'       => 'John Doe',
            'token_name'          => $fortParams['token_name'],
            'language'            => $this->language,
            'return_url'          => $this->getUrl('route.php?r=processResponse'),
        );
        if(isset($fortParams['3ds']) && $fortParams['3ds'] == 'no') {
            $postData['check_3ds'] = 'NO';
        }

        //calculate request signature
        $signature             = $this->calculateSignature($postData, 'request');
        $postData['signature'] = $signature;

        $debugMsg = "Fort Host2Host Request Parameters \n".print_r($postData, 1);
        $this->log($debugMsg);

        if ($this->sandboxMode) {
            $gatewayUrl = 'https://sbpaymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi';
        }
        else {
            $gatewayUrl = 'https://paymentservices.payfort.com/FortAPI/paymentApi';
        }

        $array_result = $this->callApi($postData, $gatewayUrl);

        $debugMsg = "Fort Host2Host Response Parameters \n".print_r($array_result, 1);
        $this->log($debugMsg);

        return  $array_result;
    }

    /**
     * Send host to host request to the Fort
     * @param array $postData
     * @param string $gatewayUrl
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function callApi($postData, $gatewayUrl)
    {
        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        $useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                //'Accept: application/json, application/*+json',
                //'Connection:keep-alive'
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $gatewayUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "compress, gzip");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // allow redirects     
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return into a variable
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); // The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, Yii::app()->params['apiCallTimeout']); // timeout in seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        //$response_data = array();
        //parse_str($response, $response_data);
        curl_close($ch);

        $array_result = json_decode($response, true);

        if (!$response || empty($array_result)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $array_result;
    }

    /**
     * calculate fort signature
     * @param array $arrData
     * @param string $signType request or response
     * @return string fort signature
     */
    public function calculateSignature($arrData, $signType = 'request')
    {
        $shaString             = '';
        ksort($arrData);
        foreach ($arrData as $k => $v) {
            $shaString .= "$k=$v";
        }

        if ($signType == 'request') {
            $shaString = $this->SHARequestPhrase . $shaString . $this->SHARequestPhrase;
        }
        else {
            $shaString = $this->SHAResponsePhrase . $shaString . $this->SHAResponsePhrase;
        }
        $signature = hash($this->SHAType, $shaString);

        return $signature;
    }

    /**
     * Convert Amount with dicemal points
     * @param decimal $amount
     * @param string  $currencyCode
     * @return decimal
     */
    public function convertFortAmount($amount, $currencyCode)
    {
        $new_amount = 0;
        $total = $amount;
        $decimalPoints    = $this->getCurrencyDecimalPoints($currencyCode);
        $new_amount = round($total, $decimalPoints) * (pow(10, $decimalPoints));
        return $new_amount;
    }

    public  function castAmountFromFort($amount, $currencyCode)
    {
        $decimalPoints    = $this->getCurrencyDecimalPoints($currencyCode);
        //return $amount / (pow(10, $decimalPoints));
        $new_amount = round($amount, $decimalPoints) / (pow(10, $decimalPoints));
        return $new_amount;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $currency
     * @param integer 
     */
    public function getCurrencyDecimalPoints($currency)
    {
        $decimalPoint  = 2;
        $arrCurrencies = array(
            'JOD' => 3,
            'KWD' => 3,
            'OMR' => 3,
            'TND' => 3,
            'BHD' => 3,
            'LYD' => 3,
            'IQD' => 3,
        );
        if (isset($arrCurrencies[$currency])) {
            $decimalPoint = $arrCurrencies[$currency];
        }
        return $decimalPoint;
    }

    public function getUrl($path)
    {
        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $this->projectUrlPath .'/'. $path;
        return $url;
    }

    public function generateMerchantReference()
    {
        return rand(0, 9999999999);
    }

    /**
     * Log the error on the disk
     */
    public function log($messages) {
        $messages = "========================================================\n\n".$messages."\n\n";
        $file = __DIR__.'/trace.log';
        if (filesize($file) > 907200) {
            $fp = fopen($file, "r+");
            ftruncate($fp, 0);
            fclose($fp);
        }

        $myfile = fopen($file, "a+");
        fwrite($myfile, $messages);
        fclose($myfile);
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param type $po payment option
     * @return string payment option name
     */
    function getPaymentOptionName($po) {
        switch($po) {
            case 'creditcard' : return 'Credit Cards';
            case 'cc_merchantpage' : return 'Credit Cards (Merchant Page)';
            case 'installments' : return 'Installments';
            case 'sadad' : return 'SADAD';
            case 'naps' : return 'NAPS';
            default : return '';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which part of the code is *not working* for you?

Comment: i am want to change this static value :   public $amount = 7150.00; that is predefined in class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access (read, modify) an instance variable (which $amount is), you have to use $this->amount from within a method.

For example.

```
$this->amount = 1000.00
```

This is not the same as:

```
$amount = 1000.00
```

It would be a very good idea to find a book on OOP, and review the top 10 list from owasp.org for security best practices.  Specifically, your code needs to be validating user input as strictly as possible before using it in redirects or sending it on to other services. Also, it looks like you may have posted some access credentials so you might want to change those.